# How directives are invoked If an element that contains a directive is added dynamically through an angular controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

After doing some search I haven't found much information in this bad practice. Let's say I have a controller that behaves like that (I know it should have been a directive and that in controllers we never do DOM manipulation but I am curious..)

```
angular.module('app').controller('test', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.addElement = function() {

            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = "text";
            //directive
            input.setAttribute("autosize","autosize");
            input.setAttribute("ng-model","dummy");
            //[ append code ]
            input.focus();



        }
    }
]);
```

and let's assume that I have a button that triggers addElement() with ng-click. How the existing autosize directive will be "triggered" to actually work. In contrast input elements that preexist and have the autosize directive work fine. I also tried $scope.apply(function() { }); around the indented code that creates the input element and it causes TypeError: undefined is not a function :/

Comment: have you tried `$compile(input)($scope);`?

Comment: wow nice thanks - I didn't know that there is a way to call $compile through a controller - I am updating the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Mohammad Shahrouri's comment above, I had to inject the `$compile` dependency in the controller and I had to add `$compile(input)($scope);` at the end:

```
angular.module('app').controller('test', ['$scope','$compile',
    function($scope, $compile) {
        $scope.addElement = function() {

            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = "text";
            //contains directive
            input.setAttribute("autosize","autosize");
            input.setAttribute("ng-model","dummy");
            //[ append code ]
            input.focus();
            $compile(input)($scope);

        }
    }
]);
```