# Angularjs - dynamically add and update DOM

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying add HTML elements through javascript that has a directive:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("day-grid")[0].innerHTML = "<div ng-uc-day-event></div>";
or
var ele = document.createElement("div");
ele.setAttribute("ng-uc-day-event","");
document.getElementsByClassName("day-grid")[0].appendChild(ele);
```

Both results in adding the `div` to `.day-grid`. I am using a directive to load template from an external file into `ng-uc-day-event`. It works as expected when it is run from the HTML file, but it doesn't work when I run the above code from the developer console.

How do I make angularjs to call the directive or evaluate the element when I am adding the element to DOM, so that the template is loaded into `div` when it is inserted into `.day-grid`?

Below is the directive I am using:

```
ulcal.directive("ngUcDayEvent", function ($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'views/dayevent.html',
    link: function (s, e, a) {
      $timeout(function () {
        s.$emit("ucDayEventLoaded");
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447885/how-directives-are-invoked-if-an-element-that-contains-a-directive-is-added-dyna

Comment: @MichailMichailidis That question is for adding the element from the controller. I know how to do that. What I want to know is how to add an element completely from outside, eg: through jquery, dev console etc. Any way that link too helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
inj = angular.injector(['ng', ApplicationName]);
inj.invoke(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
   ele = $compile("<div ng-uc-day-event></div>")($rootScope)[0];
   $(".day-grid").append(ele);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Angular to `$compile` the template and associate it with a scope. Angular will not recognise bits of HTML being inserted into the DOM at arbitrary times.

Inject the `$compile` service to wherever you are doing your DOM manipulation.

```
var container = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('day-grid')[0]);
var myDirective = angular.element('<div ng-uc-day-event></div>');

container.append(myDirective);

$compile(container)(scope);
```

Comment: This is similar to adding the element from the controller: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447885/how-directives-are-invoked-if-an-element-that-contains-a-directive-is-added-dyna. I know how to do that. What I want to know is how to add an element completely from outside, eg: through jquery, dev console etc. Any way your answer also helped me. Thank you